# Responsive resizing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a div which contains the following layout (top image): http://tinypic.com/r/287eu88/8

I am trying to work out how to move the elements to the configuration shown in the bottom image on resize/ on mobile devices but I can't work it out.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9DZSA/1/

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be good, I am a beginner so my code is probably not very good so any pointers would be great too!

Thanks!

"Links to jsFiddle.net must be accompanied by code" - Well I am not targetting a specific element but here is the html to satisfy the requirement:

LATEST PROJECT

```
 <h3 id="latestDescription">aboutaboutabout</h3>

<div id="latestSub">
     <h4 id="latestSubheading">Insert Project Name</h4>

    <p id="latestSubdescription">Out believe has request not how comfort evident.
        <br>Extremity sweetness difficult behaviour he of.
        <br>With my them if up many.</p>
</div>
<div id="latestIcons">
    <div id="latestOne">
        <img id="latestIcon1" src="http://placehold.it/80" alt ""/>
         <h5 class="latestH5">Design</h5>

        <p class="latestP">Instantly gentleman contained belonging exquisite now direction she ham.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="latestTwo">
        <img id="latestIcon2" src="http://placehold.it/80" alt ""/>tH5">Accuracy & Details</h5>
        <p class="latestP">Its hence ten smile age means. Seven chief sight far point any.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="latestThree">
        <img id="latestIcon3" src="http://placehold.it/80" alt ""/>
         <h5 class="latestH5">Posibilities</h5>

        <p class="latestP">Children me laughing we prospect answered followed.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="latestPhotoDiv">
    <img id="latestphoto" src="http://placehold.it/350" alt />
</div>
```

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (responsive, resize, elements) will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few possible ways to do it. You can select according to your need

> 1. You can use media queries in which you define different stylesheets for different screens. This is the most used way currently. 
>    Sneak Peek:
>      http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ and
>      https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries
> 2. You can use the viewport meta tag. 
>    Sneak Peek:https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag
> 3. You can design everything in % (fluid responsive) but that part is very tricky. From my experience I can say that designing a full
>      website giving everything in % is very difficult.

I will suggest you to learn media query. Its quite simple and reliable.

Comment: Thanks, I will look in to it. Are the media queries specific to devices (ie use a different stylesheet for mobiles) or is it size specific? (ie a different stylesheet will be used when window is resized to certain size on computer).

Comment: it works on size :) You can define min-width max-width and then a CSS for that

Comment: @user3403768 Please check/vote-up if my answer is able to solve your problem

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to but I don't yet have 15 reputation so it won't let me.

Comment: @user3403768 Ok. You can check it though

Answer (score 0):

You will have to take a look at [**media queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Media queries give you a way to target certain CSS properties only to specific media properties (including of course the viewport size, but also if it's print, or black and white, and so on).

Many people would suggest that you begin with a **mobile-first** approach, that is, you start by applying the CSS for the mobile, minimal version, and apply media queries at break points as your viewports get wider, enclosing your CSS like so:

```
@media (min-width: 480px){
   /* CSS goes here */
}
```